# Spring. Add child element after root element on XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling

I have following code:

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "responseClientInfo")
public class SignUpStatus {

    @XmlElement(name = "clientCode")
    private Integer clientId;

    public Integer getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(Integer clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
}
```

I get next xml:

```
<responseClientInfo>
    <clientCode>120118</clientCode>
</responseClientInfo>
```

But I need  to get next:

```
<responseClientInfo>
  <clientInfo>
        <clientCode>120118</clientCode>
  </clientInfo>    
</responseClientInfo>
```

I understand that it is possible to wrap clientCode into a class clientInfo and set those new class as xmlElement, but is it possible to do it in a more clear and elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one `XmlElementWrapper`:

```
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.ALPHABETICAL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "responseClientInfo")
public class SignUpStatus {

@XmlElement(name = "clientCode")
@XmlElementWrapper(name="clientInfo")
private Integer clientId;

public Integer getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientId(Integer clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
}
```

Comment: @XmlElementWrapper is only allowed on a collection property